Doesn't my function cover all return paths or it is compiler's bug
I have the following function that worked until my recent update of the Visual Studio
2022 compiler (17.11.4). The error I get from the compiler is : not all code paths return a value. But which path is not covered? One is return GetAllDatesWithoutLock(); and the other is a rethrow ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw(ex);? This code was working OK until the update.
public ScheduleDateTimeResponse GetAllDates()
{
    log.Info("GetAllDates before locking");
    semaphoreObject.Wait();
    try
    {
        return GetAllDatesWithoutLock();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.Name + "Error occurred.");
        log.Error(Thread.CurrentThread.Name + "Error occurred in GetAllDates:", ex);
        ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw(ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        semaphoreObject.Release();
        log.Info("GetAllDates after locking");
    }
}


How do you know that ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw never completes successfully but always throws an exception? How could the compiler know? If you replace it with a different method call, how can the compiler know that this method will throw an exception?

Technically ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw(ex) returns void.

@knittl in theory since it is a framework method compiler can know =)

@GuruStron: That doesn't sound like a good idea unless the method is part of the C# specification, or has some attribute which is specified to say "this method never returns". Allowing code to compile that violates the specification isn't a good idea IMO. (There are plenty of ways in which Roslyn does that, brokenly, which can't be fixed due to backward compatibility - but I'd still argue that it's a bug when it does so.)

@JonSkeet completely agree with that. As for the attribute - it is marked with DoesNotReturnAttribute but this is not a contract AFAIK, so it is of no use here.

Which version of VS you have updated from?

I think from 17.10.5

So, what is the best solution—to remove ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw(ex) and replace it with the throw keyword?

This should have never compiled. [DoesNotReturn] is for nullable analysis only. See also: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/69486

Maybe I did something wrong before, I have rolled back to 17.10.5 and it does not compile - you are right

"I have rolled back to 17.10.5 and it does not compile" -  you might need to force using older SDK too to check if it was working before (with global.json) - by default the latest SDK on the machine is used and when you have updated VS you highly likely installed newer SDK version. Again - the error is more correct behavior here.

I'd just add throw; after ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw(ex) (assuming there's some reason for have that there in the first place) - or possible throw new InvalidOperationException("Not expected to be reached; Throw(ex) will throw"); for clarity.

In dotnet 7 ir higher there would be UnreachableException, too.

Although ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw has a DoesNotReturnAttribute, this attribute is for nullable analysis, and not considered when analysing whether all code paths return. As far as the latter is concerned, you are just calling an ordinary method.
I would just add a throw; statement at the end of the catch block.
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.Name + "Error occurred.");
    log.Error(Thread.CurrentThread.Name + "Error occurred in GetAllDates:", ex);
    ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw(ex);
    throw;
}


where do you find DoesNotReturnAttribute - the documentation does not say anything that ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw contains this attribute?

@janci the documentation weirdly doesn’t show it, but if you go to the source code (there is a link in the documentation page), it is there.

@janci https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/5535e31a712343a63f5d7d796cd874e563e5ac14/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Runtime/ExceptionServices/ExceptionDispatchInfo.cs#L60C55-L60C78
